# How do I fix my output regarding my switch statement?

Tags: java, input, switch-statement, output, java.util.scanner

I'm having some trouble with my output in my program. What is supposed to happen is the user is to make a selection regarding which method they want to use. The program is then to go through a switch statement based on that choice and output a corresponding sum or product for whatever method and value the user entered.

However, the program displays the menu selection but only outputs the error message. I've been having this error for a while but I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I ask you please forgive my ignorance as I have not been programming very long.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sum = "S";
        String factorial = "F";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter " + sum + " to use the sum method or " + factorial + " to use the factorial method.");
        String userSelection = scan.next();

        switch (userSelection.toLowerCase()) {
            case "sum":
                System.out.println("Enter the number you want to use: ");
                int userValue = scan.nextInt();
                int userSum = sum(userValue);
                System.out.println("The resulting value for the sum method is: " + userSum);
                break;

            case "fact":
                System.out.println("Enter the number you want to use: ");
                int userFact = scan.nextInt();
                int userFactorial = fact(userFact);
                System.out.println("The resulting value for the factorial method is: " + userFactorial);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid choice.");
            }
            scan.close();
    }
    public static int sum(int num) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            sum = i + sum;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static int fact(int num) {
        int fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            fact = i * fact;
        }
        return fact;
    }
```

Comment: You ask the user to input "S" or "F", Why do you compare the input to "sum" and "fact" then?

Comment: Ah I see that is what I was doing wrong., thanks for the help!

Comment: Not to your question, but [Gauss](https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Teaching-Children-Mathematics/Blog/The-Story-of-Gauss/) noticed the sum of numbers `1` to `n` is `((n + 1) * n) / 2` (in *elementary school*).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the user input to wrong strings. You ask him to type "S" or "F" but then compare this input to "sum" and "fact" instead.